# Force compile time evaluation of constexpr with clang

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, constexpr, clang++

To force the evaluation of a `constexpr` function at compile time, I should be 
able to assign its return value to a `constexpr` variable.

```
constexpr bool const_d_ref(const double& v) { return false; }

int main() {
  constexpr double dd = 0.0;
  constexpr bool cb = const_d_ref(dd);
}
```

This seems to work fine with `g++` and `clang++`.

In order to hide the `constexpr` from the consumer, I move the actual function 
definition into the `namespace detail`, create a new function which assigns the 
return value to a `constexpr` variable and return it.

```
namespace detail {
constexpr bool const_d_ref(const double& v) { return false; }
}
constexpr bool const_d_ref(const double& v) {
  constexpr bool b = detail::const_d_ref(v);
  return b;
}
int main() {
  constexpr double dd = 0.0;
  bool b = const_t_ref(dd);
  constexpr bool cb = detail::const_t_ref(dd);
}
```

It works as expected with `g++`, but `clang++` returns a compiler error:

> error: constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a constant expression

Is what I'm doing allowed? Or is `clang` being to restrictive? Or is `gcc` being to permissive?

cpp.godbolt.org: [gcc 6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/P6mSmF) & [clang 3.8](https://godbolt.org/g/o1Cg5q)

Comment: The `double &` needs to be `constexpr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v` in `constexpr bool const_d_ref(const double& v) {` is not a compile-time expression.  Therefore `detail::const_d_ref(v)` is also not a compile-time expression.

Your example will work if you change `b` to `const`:

```
const bool b = detail::const_d_ref(v);
```

[cpp.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/PYkYnv)

Comment: Even though `v` is never used in the body?

Comment: @Yakk ... cue frantic search through the cryptonomicon known as "the standard"...

Comment: @Yakk [expr.const]/2 has pretty similar example:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7362e7bde98bb417

Comment: @Yakk:  Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  `v` *is* used in the body, in the line I quote.

Comment: It is not used in the body of `const_d_ref`.

Comment: @Yakk:  Ah, `detail::const_d_ref`, correct.  But `v` is used in `::const_d_ref`.  It is `::const_d_ref` that my first sentence refers to.  Arguments to `constexpr` functions can not ever be considered `constexpr` within said function.  However C++14 `constexpr` functions can have non-`constexpr` local variables.  For example: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L2457-L2474

Comment: But I'd like to avoid having to use `constexpr` in the main function. I guess that's not possible then.

Comment: @Ram-Z:  When you don't declare the variable `constexpr` you give the compiler permission to initialize that variable at run time, even if initialized by a `constexpr` function.